# How to write bold text in Google play App Description?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

How do I add text in bold and italics in the app description using Google play console? Can I do it using play console or will I need any other third party tool?

Answer (score 12):

It seems that you can use html tags to format your description.

```
<b>Your bold description</b>
```

Link that describes how to format your app description.
[ASOSTACK.COM](https://asostack.com/enhance-your-google-play-store-description-with-rich-formatting-and-emojis-5f50ff354e5f)